# Codeigniter, array in session, change the value of array in session in a specific key

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have a variable in session that contains array of numbers. I want to change a specific number inside that variable.
My session:

```
                $user_data = array(
                    'user_id' => $user_id,
                    'username' => $username,
                    'logged_in' => true,

                    // 20 slots, the counting starts from 0, the last slot's position
                    // is 19.
                    'slots_id' => array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                );
```

So, slots_id is the variable that i want to access. I need to change the last number, it.In my controller i have the following.

```
$this->session->set_userdata('slots_id'[19], 100);
```

Here i'm trying to set the last slot's value to 100. But the "[19]" that i put there causes error.

```
A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Uninitialized string offset: 19
```

Google did not help me in my current situation, thank you for your time.

Comment: Did you try `$this->session->set_userdata('slots_id[19]', 100);` ? Your code is attempting to update position 19 of the 'slots_id' string and going out of bounds because `slots_id` is an 8 character string. The small change I'm proposing would change the value of the `slot_id` array with index 19

Comment: `'slots_id[19]'` just passes 'slots_id[19]' as a string literal. If you look at the documentation for this method, in two-argument form the first argument is a string of the key you're trying to find. https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways around your problem:

`$this->session->set_userdata('slots_id'[19], 100);` is not attempting to assign a value of 100 to the array element on index 19 for the `$slots_id` array. It's trying to set a value of 100 as the 20th character (index 19) of the `'slots_id'` string, which goes out of bounds.

You may try:
`$this->session->set_userdata('slots_id[19]', 100);`

Or even better, remove the full element from session, update it and reset it:

```
$aux = $this->session->userdata('slots_id');
$aux[19] = 100;
$this->session->unset_userdata('slots_id');
$this->session->set_userdata('slots_id', $aux);
```

it's a bit more code, but my advice would be to always replace session data rather than update it on the fly.

Comment: It works, but for some reason all other numbers become zero, except the number that i changed while using your code. Any other ideas? Thank you for you time and answer btw.

Comment: @VictorTheBeast which way did you go? directly editing the array in the session data or fetching it, modifying it and then unset/set the array element in the session?

Comment: My mistake. I was using for loop to set the array each time, which was causing it to always have a single index on it. This time i set the array when the loop is over, so now i have all of my slots just where i wanted them. I took your advice, i set all slots at once, i'm not updating just one index on the fly. You gave me good advice and i solved my problem. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

`Uninitialized string offset` errors in PHP have a vast amount of documentation around them. You are getting this error because you are not referencing index 19 of an Array, you're referencing it of a string, which is exactly what 'slots_id' is in this instance. 'slots_id' is 8 characters long which means any index beyond 7 is in fact undefined.

If you have no direct access to the `$_SESSION` superglobal for some odd reason, you need to retrieve the entire `slots_id` array via the helper, update the index you need in your local copy, then update the session variable's `slots_id` array with your updated copy.